# char to int in C with struct values

Tags: c, variables, char, int

I am trying to compare two chars with each other but treating them as integers. These are struct values in a linked list. I have printed out `temp->next->variable` and `temp->variable` and confirmed that the if statement should hold, `ex: 3 > 2`. But I'm thinking it might not work because they are `char`.

Will the fact that they are `char` values have an impact on the comparison?

```
if(temp->next->variable > temp->variable)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: `'3' > '2'` is true whether they're chars or ints. but `'6' > 'H'` would be false, since that's `ascii(54) > ascii(72)`

Comment: Be careful that `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on where you are.

Comment: Short answer: it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chars are integers, of 8-bit length, so if you're always treating the chars as ints, this will have the exact behavior you desire. Be wary, as some compilers allow char to default to unsigned, some to signed, which may create issues seemingly at random. (If both numbers have the same highest order bit, it won't make a difference, otherwise the result will be opposite what you expect, if the signed-ness is also opposite what you expect.)

If you're treating them as characters, then this will give you their lexicographical comparison, which is based on the interal integer representation of that character. It may be good to check what your locale is -- whether your program will be using look up tables of ASCII or Unicode 8-bit, or anything else.

If you still get hidden issues, a common mistake is having many layered pointers, and even though the arrow [->] is used throughout, you may still need to apply a de-reference [*], or else you'll secretly be testing their relative locations in memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed.

The usual arithmetic conversion includes the integer promotion that particularly means that objects of type `char` are converted to objects of type `int`

Take into account that type `char` can behave either as type `unsigned char` or `signed char`. So you can get different results of the comparison if sign bits of objects of type `char` are set.